# Pre-populate jQuery UI Token Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, user-interface, token

I just started using the jQuery UI Token,
I'm trying to figure out how to pre-populate fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#viewerMusicGenre").tokenInput([
        {id: 1, name: "Love Songs & Romantic"},
        {id: 2, name: "Pop"},
        {id: 3, name: "Rock"},
        {id: 4, name: "Country"},
        {id: 5, name: "Dance"},
        {id: 6, name: "Classical"},
        {id: 7, name: "Soul"},
        {id: 8, name: "RnB"},
        {id: 9, name: "Metal"},
        {id: 10, name: "Jazz"},
        {id: 11, name: "Drum and Bass"},
        {id: 12, name: "House"},
        {id: 13, name: "Children"},
        {id: 14, name: "Spiritual"},
        {id: 15, name: "Christian"},
        {id: 16, name: "Klezmer"},
        {id: 17, name: "Arabic"},
        {id: 18, name: "Hindu"},
        {id: 19, name: "Reggae"},
        {id: 20, name: "Industrial"},
        {id: 21, name: "Indie"},
        {id: 22, name: "Electronica"}
    ]);
});
</script>
```

I understand I need to add this to the function:

```
prePopulate: [
            {id: 3, name: "Rock"},
            {id: 5, name: "Dance"},
            {id: 8, name: "RnB"}]
```

I don't know how to add, as I tried different ways but keep getting a sintax error.

Any help is appreciated.
Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/IhIkIsoW/2/edit

You do not need <strike>to populate ... neither</strike> the "ready" check.
Just add the script tag after the element like I did in the jsbin. 
You should also take a look at this lib http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/, it might be a better choice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>    
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery Tokeninput Demo</title>    
</head>
<body>    
<input type="text" id="viewerMusicGenre"/>    
<script>
  $("#viewerMusicGenre").tokenInput([
    {id: 1, name: "Love Songs & Romantic"},
    {id: 2, name: "Pop"},
    {id: 3, name: "Rock"},
    {id: 4, name: "Country"},
    {id: 5, name: "Dance"},
    {id: 6, name: "Classical"},
    {id: 7, name: "Soul"},
    {id: 8, name: "RnB"},
    {id: 9, name: "Metal"},
    {id: 10, name: "Jazz"},
    {id: 11, name: "Drum and Bass"},
    {id: 12, name: "House"},
    {id: 13, name: "Children"},
    {id: 14, name: "Spiritual"},
    {id: 15, name: "Christian"},
    {id: 16, name: "Klezmer"},
    {id: 17, name: "Arabic"},
    {id: 18, name: "Hindu"},
    {id: 19, name: "Reggae"},
    {id: 20, name: "Industrial"},
    {id: 21, name: "Indie"},
    {id: 22, name: "Electronica"}
  ], {
    prePopulate: [
      {id: 3, name: "Rock"},
      {id: 5, name: "Dance"},
      {id: 8, name: "RnB"}
    ]
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have  the same but still no values are being shown on page load. I want some values  at least 3 to be there before the user interacts with the field. hence "pre-populated". Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I updated the answer. Isn't it solved? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't see it before! It's solved! :D